# Coloring slices of pie chart in matplotlib python

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, pie-chart

Assume, I have a pie chart as following; and I would like to color the slices based on some values in a vector, as a gradient between blue to red. Blue for -1, and red +1, there is no value greater than 1 nor less than -1.

```
fracs = [33,33,33]
starting_angle = 90
axis('equal')
patches, texts, autotexts = pie(fracs, labels = None, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)

print patches[2]

for item in autotexts:
    item.set_text("")

subplots_adjust(left=0.125, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=0.0, hspace=-0.4)


savefig('/home/superiois/Downloads/projectx3/GRAIL/pie2')
show()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958835/matplotlib-color-gradient-in-patches

Answer (score 1):

```
fracs = [33,33,33]
starting_angle = 90
axis('equal')

color_vals = [-1, 0, 1]

my_norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(-1, 1) # maps your data to the range [0, 1]
my_cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet') # can pick your color map

patches, texts, autotexts = pie(fracs, labels = None, autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90,
                colors=my_cmap(my_norm(color_vals)))

print patches[2]

for item in autotexts:
    item.set_text("")


subplots_adjust(left=0.125, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=0.0, hspace=-0.4)

show()
```

You can set the color of the patches with the `colors` kwarg.  You can leverage the existing color mapping code (used in `imshow` for example) to generate the gradient you want.  The `Normalize` object takes care of normalizing your data to the range that the color maps expect as input, and the color map converts the float to a color.

[`Normalize` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize)

[`pie` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie)

[ColorMap doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap)

Comment: The question is putting gradient on each slice. I expected to see slides by "blue, white, and red".

Comment: @user702846 That is not the question you asked, you should clarify your OP.