# Python matplotlib - how to create a pie chart with colour representing the frequency?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart, color-mapping

I was wondering how can I create a pie chart which has equal sized segments where the colour per segment represents the frequency for that segment?

This is also known as a clock glyph. I aim to split the pie chart into 24 segments and plot some frequency data for hours where the frequency will determine the colour of the hour segment based upon a colourmap.

The data would be something like this (for a 5 hour period):

```
data = [3,34,76,11,90]
```

And my colourmap (mycm) is:

```
mycm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycm',['k','r'])]
```

To create the equal segments I guess I use something like:

```
plt.pie([1,1,1,1,1], labels=None, shadow=False, radius=0.5)
```

But how can I then colour these using the colourmap I have defined based upon the frequency values in data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The code you need is below and was adapted from [Coloring slices of pie chart in matplotlib python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639668/coloring-slices-of-pie-chart-in-matplotlib-python).  Basically you have the fracs for each slice all the same value (so that all the slices are same size), but the color changes via the colors parameter.  You map the colors based on the frequency or anything else you may want.

```
fracs = ones(len(data))*1/len(data)
my_norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(min(data),max(data)) #this is how we will map our data

c1 = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycm',['k','r'])

plt.pie(fracs, labels=None, shadow=False, radius=0.5, colors=c1(my_norm(data)))
```

Depending on the distribution of your data, you may still get a pie chart that looks like you have only a few colors because we are using a linear mapping to map data points to colors.  If you want a nonlinear map, you can change that in how you map your data (the my_norm function).  For example you could construct a color array of equal distance around the color wheel, for maximum difference between N colors, and cycle through the colors as opposed to mapping the colors.