# How to do scatter plots using a rendered ball in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to achieve a plot below:

[image]

Every point looks like a ball. The first idea came to my mind is do customization markers. I found the [Phong shading model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model) very useful to generate shading balls. But I have no idea how can I use it in matplotlib. Or is there any simpler method to achieve this?

Comment: Did you see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958835/matplotlib-color-gradient-in-patches/10995481#10995481)?

Comment: Thank u for your reply, it seems that it overlays a img Ang use a cmap. But you have plenty of points, you don’t get the speed.

Comment: You could also directly take the image of the ball and place it on the axes. Essentially like in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_annotation_box.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-demo-annotation-box-py) plus removing all the black line annotation stuff.

Comment: This seems a approach with minimum code implementation. I will try it. If matplotlib support color gradient for markers, it would do all the good. Thank u any way!

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566284/matplotlib-how-to-plot-images-instead-of-points) is an implementation without black borders. Concerning "color gradient" for markers, if you think deeper about it it would turn out that that is essentially the very same as an image. Just maybe with a different user facing API.